# jQuery reverting CSS to original state

Tags: jquery, css

I have added a click event using jQuery to change my CSS. The click works and the CSS changes, but then jQuery continues to run and eventually reverts the CSS to the original state.

jQuery code:

```
    $('.myClass').click(function(){
        $('.myClass').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
    });
```

CSS code:

```
   .myClass {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     background: red;
     visibility:visible;
   }
```

Like I said, the click works and the element gets hidden. However, it reverts instantly when jQuery finishes running through its code. Using Google Chrome's debugger tool, I see this is the point in the jQuery code that reverts the CSS back to having the element visible.

jQuery's code (line 4116):

```
    if ( !(eventHandle = elemData.handle) ) {
        eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
            // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
            // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
            return typeof jQuery !== strundefined && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
line 4116      jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
        };
    }
```

I guess I don't understand what is happening with this jQuery code and why my CSS gets reverted?

Comment: can you post all of your jquery and your html? I have run this code and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might try just toggling a class which has 'visibility:hidden' to avoid the issue altogether.

```
#CSS
.vh{
    visibility:hidden
    #or you could use display:none
}

#Javascript
$('.myClass').click(function(){
    $('.myClass').toggleClass('vh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that as your page runs, there is some other CSS or jQuery running and overwriting the 'visibility:hidden;' I would also recommend toggling your class and using 'display:block;' and 'display:none' over 'visibility:hidden'.

If you provide the rest of your HTML and jQuery I may be able to give you a more precise answer.